# Instant App : Can we use dynamic bundle only for Instant app and not for main app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle

I have two separate codebases one for the main app and one for Instant app. I am not using Android App Bundles in the main app. Can I use the Dynamic module only in the Instant App as the feature plugin is deprecated? And Can I upload it on play store without changing the main app to support App bundles?

I know it's recommended that there should be one codebase and one should use instant-enabled app bundle.

Comment: are you getting two launcher activities from the app list?. as I have enabled intent filter main and launcher for an instant app and base module.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/instant-delivery